# Do I have to use PresentModalViewController?

Tags: ios, core-animation

I'm doing some "interesting" view transitions, and I'm finding myself working around the functionality of "presentModalViewController" in a way that doesn't feel right.

I'd prefer to take total control over the presentation of the modal view controller's view and skip "presentModalViewController" altogether.

However, I'm not sure about the ramifications of doing this.

Currently, I've got code that looks works something like like this (this is just a pseudo-code example, and I can't use the built in transitions, they won't do what I need):

```
    // Create the child view controller:
    ModalViewController * child = [[ModalViewController alloc] init];

    // Present it:
    [parentViewController presentModalViewController:child animated:NO];

    // This rect is what the child view's ultimate "destination" should be,
    // and, what the parent view's old frame was:
    CGRect frame = child.view.frame;

    // Put the parent view controller's view back in the window:
    [child.view.window insertSubview:parentViewController.view belowSubview:child.view];

    // Show it if it's hidden:
    [parentViewController.view setHidden:NO];

    // Put the parent back where it was:
    [parentViewController.view setFrame:frame];

    // Put the child at the "top" of the screen (the bottom edge
    // of the child's view is at the top of the screen):
    [child.view setFrame:CGRectMake(frame.origin.x, 
                                  frame.origin.y - frame.size.height, 
                                  frame.size.width, 
                                  frame.size.height)];

    // Animate a transition which slide the parent and child views 
    // down together:
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.7 animations:^(void) {

        child.view.frame = frame;
        parentViewController.view.frame = CGRectMake(frame.origin.x, 
                                    frame.origin.y + frame.size.height, 
                                    frame.size.width, 
                                    frame.size.height);

    } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
        // We're done, remove the parent view from the window
        // like it's supposed to be:
        [parentViewController.view removeFromSuperview]; 
    }];

    [child release];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want to have `UIKit` set `modalViewController` and control the presentation and dismissal of the child view controller, then don't. You can skip the `presentModalViewController:animated:` call and manually add or remove subviews, or if you want to switch to an entirely new view controller then disconnect the old one's `view` from the heirarchy and connect the new one, etc. Other ways of presenting include `UINavigationController` or a `UITabBarController`, and they don't use the `modalViewController` methods.

To be more specific, you should set the [`rootViewController`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIWindow_Class/UIWindowClassReference/UIWindowClassReference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIWindow/rootViewController) property of your application's `UIWindow` to the new view controller.

Docs say:

> The root view controller provides the content view of the window. Assigning a view controller to this property (either programmatically or using Interface Builder) installs the view controller’s view as the content view of the window. If the window has an existing view hierarchy, the old views are removed before the new ones are installed.

Note that the docs mention an automatic process of installing the `view` as the content view of the heirarchy. What I'm saying is you can use the provided automatic methods - `UIWindow` for root views, `modalViewController` and other systems for non-root views - or you can do it manually, but it's accomplishing the same thing. Particularly since the `rootViewController` property has only existed since iOS 4, and applications prior to this used auto-generated default code of `[window addSubview:rootView]` at launch.

If `UIKit` has some extra magic occurring in `[UIWindow setRootViewController:]` I'm totally prepared to be corrected on this though.

Comment: I think that's not quite right though... I believe, *at minimum*, if I do as you're suggesting, I'd have to call [child viewWillAppear:...], [child viewWillDisappear:...] etc to keep feeding the child UIViewController the messages its supposed to be getting. Additionally, I think there are other concerns, like setting parent view controller references and such. I think you're over-simplifying it... but maybe I'm totally off base?

Comment: As long as you operate on the *root* view controller when you disconnect and reconnect views (i.e remove the root view controller's view from the `UIWindow` and add the new controller's subview to it), all `viewWill` and `viewDid` events should be fired on the new view controller. The idea with `UIKit` is that events propagate down the heirarchy, so as long as you ensure that a heirarachy still exists (under your `UIWindow`), everything will worke exactly as expected.

Comment: @Steve: Addendum to the above comment, event propagation only works within what `UIKit` wants you to do. So `viewWillAppear:` etc will work on immediate subviews of a view controller which is being directly presented by `UIKit` as the current view controller, but if you have a view controller inside another one (Apple says don't do that) then it's not going to be sent those messages.

Comment: If I re-use rootViewController everywhere, I'll have to retain the old controller somewhere else. Also, you're making it increasingly difficult to create any sort of hierarchy. For example, if I display a modal view to ask the user some questions, then dismiss it, I'll have to hold on to that "last" view controller somewhere (presumably on a stack). UIViewController already has mechanisms for dealing with this. I think you're diverging even further from an ideal solution.

Comment: Yes, if you want to do that then use a `UINavigationController`. You were asking about `modalViewController` though, and I'm saying that you don't need to use `modalViewController` because there are numerous ways to accomplish the same ends (which are either no less complicated, or require one extra variable). To display a modal view, you'll need to initialise it, so just declare that variable at object-level rather than inside the scope of a function. Either you hold the reference to what you present or `UIKit` does, there isn't really a third option.

Comment: There is no such thing as `modalViewController`. `UINavigationController` isn't the same as displaying a `UIViewController` modally from any other given `UIViewController`. "To display a modal view, you'll need to initialize it, so just declare that variable at object-level rather than inside the scope of a function." But you're proposing replacing rootViewController. Definitely doesn't make the situation any better than my sample code in the post.

Comment: Are you sure there's no such thing as [`modalViewController`](http://developer.apple.com/library/iOS/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIViewController/modalViewController)? This is the property that `UIKit` uses to hold a reference to the presented view. If you want to do it outside of `UIKit`, you'll need to hold a reference to it somewhere else. Other than that, just animate the appearance and dismissal however you want, and you should be done. We should move the discussion to chat, but I'm at work so I should get back to it.

Comment: @Steve let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/2648/discussion-between-darvids0n-and-steve)

Comment: You were using it in the same context as other classes (UINavigationController). That property, in-particular, is read only. Only way to use it is via "presentModalViewController".

Comment: That's why I said "If you want to do it outside of `UIKit`, you'll need to hold a reference to [the presented view] somewhere else."